# Programa que permite ver números entre dos entradas

Tags: c++

¿Cómo puedo resolver este ejercicio de programación?

> Realizar un programa que permite ver los números que están entre dos números ingresado por teclado en c++.

Éste es el código que tengo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;

    printf( "\n   Introduzca el primer valor: " );
    scanf( "%d", &i );
    printf( "\n   Introduzca el segundo valor : " );
    scanf( "%d", &j );
    for(i=i+1;i<j;i++)
    {

        printf("%d \n", i);
    }
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Christop Punguil, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado!, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar las variables a y b en vez de i y j, y usa una variable diferente para el for, en este caso te remiendo usar k asi:

## include

int main()
{
    int i, j, k;

```
printf( "\n   Introduzca el primer valor: " );
scanf( "%d", &i );
printf( "\n   Introduzca el segundo valor : " );
scanf( "%d", &j );
for(k=i+1;k<j;k++)
{

    printf("%d \n", k);
}
system ("pause");
return 0;
```

}

supongo que si pones numeros seguidos te podria dar error pero esa es una posible solucion.

Suerte.

Comment: Por favor organiza el código. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás en C++ te recomiendo que utilices las siguientes funciones:

Cambia:

```
printf( "\n   Introduzca el primer valor: " );
```

por

```
cout << "Introduzca el primer valor: " << endl;
```

Cambia:

```
scanf( "%d", &j );
```

por

```
cin >> j;
```

Antecede lo anterior con

```
using namespace std;
```

Un saludo.